# android draw over image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-canvas

I am creating a paint app but i am not able to draw /paint anything over an image please help me out :

```
public class DrawingSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private Boolean _run;
    protected DrawThread thread;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    public boolean isDrawing = true;
    public DrawingPath previewPath;

    private CommandManager commandManager;

    public DrawingSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        getHolder().addCallback(this);


        commandManager = new CommandManager();
        thread = new DrawThread(getHolder());
    }

    private Handler previewDoneHandler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            isDrawing = false;
        }
    };

    class DrawThread extends  Thread{
        private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;


        public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder){
            mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;

        }

        public void setRunning(boolean run) {
            _run = run;
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {
            Canvas canvas = null;
            while (_run){
                if(isDrawing == true){
                    try{
                        canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                        if(mBitmap == null){
                          //  mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                             mBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.splashscreen);

                        }
                //       final Canvas c = new Canvas (mBitmap);
                        mBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.splashscreen);

                   //     c.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                       canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);


                     //   commandManager.executeAll(c,previewDoneHandler);
                     //   previewPath.draw(c);

                        canvas.drawBitmap (mBitmap, 0,  0,null);
                    } finally {
                        mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }


                }

            }

        }
    }


    public void addDrawingPath (DrawingPath drawingPath){
        commandManager.addCommand(drawingPath);
    }
   // Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter);




    public boolean hasMoreRedo(){
        return commandManager.hasMoreRedo();
    }

    public void redo(){
        isDrawing = true;
        commandManager.redo();


    }

    public void undo(){
        isDrawing = true;
        commandManager.undo();
    }

    public boolean hasMoreUndo(){
        return commandManager.hasMoreUndo();
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(){
        return mBitmap;
    }


    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,  int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);;
    }


    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean retry = true;
        thread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // we will try it again and again...
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not working".  And also please don't dump all your code here assuming that somebody will wade through it.  Only include **relevant** pieces of code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it easier on yourself and split your application across multiple surfaceviews. Use framelayout so that you can control the order of the views. I assume you want to be able to handle touch events (its a paint program right?) so handle those in one view and your drawing in another that way the code will be more manageable. Create two custom surfaceviews (In my case one was a GLSurfaceView, and the other was a SurfaceView). One view implements the image and the second can handle a GUI with graphics and or buttons. The key is creating a custom GLSurfaceView (or in your case two Surfaceviews) in XML that uses the class names of the extended SurfaceViews. Also you must make the GUI view transparent. So your Surface view that calls your drawing class and handles touch events would have code like this:

```
public class MainSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView
//Constructor
public MainSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {       
    super(context, attrs);
    Log.d(TAG, "Constructor called...");
    this.context = context;

    mRenderer = new MainRenderer();
    setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0); 

    setRenderer(mRenderer);
    getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);    

    setZOrderOnTop(true);

    //Render only when there is a change
    setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);         
}

//TouchEvent handler
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent called...");
    x = event.getX();
    y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        float dx = x - mPreviousX;
        float dy = y - mPreviousY;

        //Reverse direction of rotation if above midline
        if (y > getHeight() / 2) {
            dx = dx * -1;
        }

        //Reverse direction of rotation if of the midline
        if (y < getWidth() / 2) {
            dy = dy * -1;
        }

        Main.mAngle += (dx + dy) * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR;

        TextView txtView = (TextView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.mangle);
        txtView.setText("Angle: " + String.valueOf(Main.mAngle));

        requestRender();
    }

    mPreviousX = x;
    mPreviousY = y;

    return true;
}
```

Put you image to be drawn on a separate surface view (it will also make it easier to change the image). So you Activity class would have code like this (note my second view is a GLsurfaceview):

```
 public class Main extends Activity {
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called...");
    Log.d(TAG, "state is: " + state.toString());
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // When working with the camera, it's useful to stick to one orientation.
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    //Set full screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Substantiate surfaces
    cameraView = (CameraView) findViewById(R.id.camera);
    mGLView = (MainSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.glSurfaceView);        

    //Initialize TextViews
    txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mangle);
    txtView.setText("Angle: " + String.valueOf(mAngle)); 


    }
}
```

Hope that helps a little...